# I suspect someone entered my server via SSH after I created a pem file for the SSH access key. What I can learned about it?

Tags: ssh

I created an `id_rsa` key in my server with `ssh-keygen -b 4096` without a passphrase. I added my `id_rsa.pub` into `.ssh/authorized_keys` and downloaded my private `id_rsa` key into local PC and changed it into a `pem` file.

I tested the SSH access with my `pem` file in a terminal and Filezilla SFTP. It worked.

The next morning I realized that I can't access the host by SSH with my `pem` key. Then I tried to access it without the `pem` key and happily I could access it.

I checked `authorized_keys`, it's empty and only one public key left.

I checked `/var/log/auth.log`, it's empty too. The only log entry was 10 hours old.

The suspect is deleting command history too.

My `sites-available` in my Nginx config was deleted too. Even my `www/` folder is empty.

My MariaDB is uninstalled.

I wonder why the suspect is not deleting my SearX service.

I already configured my firewall too. Here is my firewall access:

Inbound

- TCP 80
- TCP 443
- TCP (My SSH Port)

Outbound

- TCP 80
- TCP 443
- UDP 53 (For DNS)

What can I learn from it?
What mistake occurred to allow this to happen?

Comment: Might you have some automation that manages (and can overwrite) your authorized_keys file? Also: you should generate private keys on the system that will use them, not the system that will use the public key. I do not recommend transferring private keys between computers.

Comment: @AdamKatz I use scp for transfer my key. I don't know is this safe or not.

Comment: scp itself is plenty secure. The issue is that each system that has had access to a key increases your risk. It should be minor, because presumably you trust that system has not been breached, but it's better to have never exposed the private key to any other system. However, that was a secondary concern. **I suspect you have automation that overwrites your authorized_keys file.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect either your SSH keys are leaked from somewhere or you might have a vulnerable application hosted on the server that has a remote command execution vulnerability. Couple of things that I'll recommend you to do immediately:

1. Rotate all the private SSH keys, even the newly created one
2. Check for any unknown users in `/etc/passwd`
3. Restrict SSH from your IP only, reference [here](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/restrict-ssh-login-to-a-specific-ip-or-host/).
4. Check for unknown/malicious connections established via `netstat -ano` command
5. Check for [malicious cron jobs](https://www.sandflysecurity.com/blog/linux-malware-persistence-with-cron/)
6. If you are hosting anything on the server, you need to audit that as well if there is Remote Command Execution in that application or not.
7. Monitor the access logs of the application, if present, to detect anomalies.